# How can I replicate an array multiple times to create a 3d array in R?

Tags: r, arrays, replicate

I have an array (`mask`) that I am using as a Land Sea mask in R of size 189x420.

I want to replicate this array to the 3-dimensional size of my dataset (let's call it `sample_data`) so that I can multiply one by the other to apply a land mask to my `sample_data` using the command below:

```
masked_data<- gridArithmetics(sample_data, mask, operator = "+")
```

If my `sample_data` is 60x189x420, I want to replicate my Land Sea Mask 60 times and create a new array of size 60x189x420.

I have tried:

```
x<-replicate(mask,5)
```

But this returns a 3d array of size 189x420x60. If I use `aperm` to try and rotate/transpose it, I end up with an array of size 60x420x189, which is not useful as this is a Land mask and I don't want to transpose the data within each individual array.

How can I replicate my `mask` array to create a 3d array of size 60x189x420?

As an follow-on/alternative, is there any sort of dot notation in r that could be used to multiply one array (`mask`) (189x420) by 3-dimensional data (`sample_data` of size 60x189x420) so that the land mask is multiplied by each individual array within the sample data (so multiplication occurs 60 times to create a new (masked) array the same size as `sample_data`)?

Comment: How are you using `aperm`? I'd suggest `aperm(x, c(3, 2, 1))`.

Comment: ahh...I was just using aperm(x), but if I use aperm(x,c(3,1,2)) that gives the dimensions in the order I want. That doesn't reshape the data within the arrays in any way then? it only moves the order of the dimesnsions around? Many thanks.